# Use common node package in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, typescript-typings

I'm trying to use a common node module ( [websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket) ) that's not made for TS in my Angular2 app.I also installed [@types/websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/websocket) and imported it in my service this way:

```
import * as WebSocket from 'websocket';
```

or

```
import { client } from 'websocket';
```

and instantiate that, there is no errors in VScode or on ngBuild, but in my browser console I got this error:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_websocket__.client is not a constructor
```

but it is actually a constructor! I use it in expressjs and regular node and every thing is ok tehre.

Comment: Please look @ this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/faq) if you need to import third party modules into Angular it has a dedicated question for typings as well as without typings.

Comment: I had tested both solutions( with and without typings ), but webpack errors are still there.

Comment: Can you create a plunker for the same?

Comment: Sorry but that's hard for me, it has a lot of components and services :(

Comment: Just for this component not the whole. I will try to import this module but i want.to know what you want to use in this module

Comment: I added parts of the code that related to this problem. https://plnkr.co/edit/Az6H4s1LRNVh49PtY5Bx

Comment: Will check and let u knw its late in my Country 2 am

Comment: It's midnight in mine too :D thanks

Comment: did you try using third party libs of angular https://github.com/afrad/angular2-websocket/blob/master/src/angular2-websocket.ts

Comment: Y, but this lib doesn't support the form of handshake that I want.

Comment: there are many as i was researching you many get what you want that was the reason i told

Comment: I'm going to switch my server api to use one of these angular modules, but I can't understand why I can't use common node modules like this in angular with webpack.

Comment: you can there is no problem in that as i have no idea of that lib so i was stating i was successfully able to load it into my app but i dnt know its functionalities

Comment: May be it can't run on browser, donno!

Comment: let me give one more try